# Schedule Push Notifications on parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I've implemented push notification in my android app using parse.com , every time I've to send a notification , I go to parse.com, compose it and send. I want something like that I can schedule a push notification to be sent daily at a fixed time say 9:00 am.I've read something like that on this website :

> Sending scheduled push notifications is not currently supported by the
>   Android SDK. Take a look at the REST API, JavaScript SDK or the
>   Parse.com push console.

By going through REST API and JavaScript sdk ,

https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/REST
https://parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/JavaScript

I got that still it's not possible to schedule a push to be sent daily automatically.We can schedule a single push to be sent later using these services. Is there any way to implement it? Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the context in which you are trying to use scheduled notifcations? i.e why do you need it?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Parse feature [background jobs](http://blog.parse.com/2013/09/04/introducing-background-jobs/). It only allows one background job to run at a time, but it should satisfy your requirements as long as they are not too lavish.

You can schedule a background job through the console or via the REST api such as a background job to send out your push notifications. You could schedule them to be sent every so often or at a specific time each day.

Its very simple to use, so hopefully that works!